# Laravel HasManyThrough relationship while including Trashed items

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to include soft deleted items with HasManyThrough relationship,

I tried adding `->withTrashed();` to it, but then I got this error:

> BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyThrough::withTrashed()

Is it possible to force Laravel skip that `where table.deleted_at is null` in a relationship?

Comment: Can you please post your code regarding your relationship here?

Comment: Could you plz add your models / controller ?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but responding for anyone that has the same issue.

if your are using HasManyThrough and want to fetch also the soft deleted records. there is a scope in the HasManyThrough relationship that can include them.
You should use it like follow :

```
$yourModel->yourHasManyThroughRelation()->withTrashedParents()->withTrashed();
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work the way you are trying.
I made an example to make it more clear to understand:

`Group::with('users')->get();`

And in the `Group` model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, UserGroup::class, 'group_id', 'id', 'id', 'user_id')->withTrashed();
}
```